# Push Notification To an Android Based Smart Watch from an Android Phone via Bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth, push-notification

is there a way to push notification to another android device via bluetooth?
i have been looking at the bluetooth chat sample code but it seems like it is very different from trying to push notification via bluetooth as that is more like a text client and needs both apps to be running. 
I am a beginner in android development and any help as to what i should look at will be helpful and appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> is there a way to push notification to another android device via bluetooth?

Insofar as if you have your app running on both devices, you can "push" any data that you want.

> that is more like a text client and needs both apps to be running

Your scenario needs both apps to be running as well.

Now, the title of your question refers to a "smart watch".

Various wearable devices have their own APIs that support a "notification" pattern (e.g., SONY SmartWatch and SW2). Those APIs may use Bluetooth or Bluetooth LE under the covers. You are certainly welcome to use such APIs, but generally those will be device-specific. Android Wear will be one API that is more in common across some wearable models, but it handle the concept of notifications itself.